# jQuery Dynamic Table data get web services, but data not paging and search

Tags: jquery

My method. My soap services get data json format.

```
function TumOlaylarlist() {
       VeriGetir("TumOlaylar",
              function (response) {
                  var data23 = response["d"] ? response.d : response;
                  console.info(data23);
                  var result = "";
                  for (var i = 0; i < data23.length; i++) {
                      result += "<tr class='gradeA success'>";
                      result += "<td>" + data23[i].ILCE_ADI + "</td>";
                      result += "<td>" + data23[i].MAHALLE_ADI + "</td>";
                      //  result += "<td>" + data23[i].YOL_ADI + "</td>";
                      result += "<td>" + data23[i].KAPI_NO + "</td>";
                      result += "<td>" + data23[i].ACIKLAMA + "</td>";
                      result += "<td>" + data23[i].ISTASYON_ISMI + "</td>";
                      result += "<td>" + data23[i].OLAYTIPI + "</td>";
                      result += "<td>" + data23[i].DURUMU + "</td>";
                      //result += "<li>" + data23[i].ILCE_ADI + data[i].MAHALLE_ADI + data[i].YOL_ADI + data[i].KAPI_NO + data[i].KAPI_ISMI + data[i].ISTASYON_ISMI + data[i].OLAYTIPID + data[i].ISIM + data[i].SOYISIM + "</li>";
                      //$('#ilce').data23[i].ILCE_ADI;
                      result += "</tr>";
                  }
                  $("#datatable tbody").html(result);
                  //if (_dataTable) {
                  //    _dataTable.destroy();
                  //}
                  //_dataTable = $('#data-table').dataTable({
                  //    data: data23
                  //});


              },
              function (xhr, status, message) {

                  console.error(xhr);
              }
          );
       //  console.log("part 2");
   };
```

My `verigetir` function

```
 function VeriGetir(methodName, succes, error) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webserUrl + methodName,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: succes,
        error: error
    });
   }
```

I want my services to get data and run my datatable update-paging and search attribute.. I write search box a word, my datatable empty.
My datatable empty.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {    
           $('#datatable').dataTable(function () {        

           });
           TumOlaylarlist();
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you load all your data at once and do not intended to do server side processing like searching, filtering then try adding  `"serverSide": false`

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
   $('#datatable').dataTable(function () {        
       "serverSide": false
   });
   TumOlaylarlist();
});
```

If you want to do serverside processing then there'll be more work to do on the serverside..

Comment: Do you get any erros on clientside as you fill in searchbox?

Comment: I dont get any eror but ı write searchbox a character my datatable record empty(remove).

Comment: you have the datatype as `json` but I remember that the datatables site has only an example using `jsonp` at https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/jsonp.html . Although I am not 100% if they differ but what I did in a similar situation was to build a webservice that has very much the same structure as given at the ajax tab of the given page. So be sure to return the right document with the right datatype and valid jsonp structure as in that page...

Comment: Can you show us your json structure even if by replacing real data with fake ones? Or give the URL to that service if it is public, so that I can test?